Duplex stream back-pressure: MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected
I've got the following duplex stream. Input is a CSV string. When the limit of CSV lines is reached, a new CSV is created and added to a ZIP archive. So the pipeline flow is this:
CSV STRING ---> MY DUPLEX ---> ZIP ARCHIVE STREAM CONTAINING N CSV FFILES ---> DO SOMETHING (e. g. upload to S3)

When running this with large files where I pipe the result (the zip archive stream) into an S3 upload, I get the following warning MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 drain listeners added to [PassThrough].
Here is my Duplex stream. I'm pretty sure I got something confused about the backpressure handling. So my question is: How can I solve backpressure issue while getting rid of the warning / potential memory leak? And do I actually need to handle backpressure myself or not?
import { Duplex, PassThrough } from "stream";
import archiver from "archiver";

export class ArchiveSplitter extends Duplex {
  private _currentFile: PassThrough | undefined;
  private _readable: archiver.Archiver;
  private _fileCounter: number = 1;
  private _lineCounter: number = 1;

  constructor(
    private readonly basename: string,
    private readonly limit = 90000,
  ) {
    super();

    const _readable = archiver("zip");
    this._readable = _readable;

    _readable.pause();

    this.once("finish", async () => {
      this._currentFile && this._currentFile.end();
      await this._readable.finalize();
      this._readable.end();
    });

    _readable.on("end", async () => {
      void this.push(null);
    });

    // forward errors
    _readable.on("error", (err) => void this.emit("error", err));
  }

  _construct(callback: (error?: Error | null) => void): void {
    callback(null);
  }

  _destroy(err: Error) {
    this._readable.destroy(err);
  }

  _write(chunk: any, _: BufferEncoding, callback: (error?: Error | null) => void) {
    if (!this._currentFile) {
      this.startFile();
    }

    const ok = this._currentFile!.write(chunk);

    if (!ok) {
      this._currentFile?.once("drain", callback);
    }

    if (this._lineCounter++ === this.limit && !!this._currentFile) {
      this._currentFile.end();
      this._currentFile = undefined;
    }

    callback(null);
  }

  _read(size?: number) {
    const chunk = this._readable.read(size);
    if (chunk !== null) this.push(chunk);
    else this._readable.once("readable", () => void this._read());
  }

  private startFile() {
    this._currentFile = new PassThrough();
    const name = `${this.basename}-${this._fileCounter++}.csv`;
    this._readable = this._readable.append(this._currentFile, { name });
    this._lineCounter = 1;
  }
}


